# JavaScript verify email by SMTP

Tags: php, javascript, email, smtp, email-validation

I would like to enable my website form to check if the email inserted by my visitor is valid and exist before allowing them submit the web form.

I do understand there is many Javascript to check the email pattern validation. But I need something such as SMTP Email Checking or Validating.

The email inserted by visitor must be valid format and also existed, this is to prevent visitor inserts invalid email, incorrect email address, as well as spamming email address.

Please kindly provide a tutorial link for validate the Email by using Javascript.

I believe server-side scripting can doing it, but I need an instant response to the web form before web visitor select the submit button for form submission.

Comment: There's no such thing as instant response when you have to query a server (The SMTP server in this case)

Comment: Instant is not possible, it needs to make at least one round-trip to the server; however, you could do a check on blur (using ajax)

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot verify the existence of an email, unless you send one and the receiver on the other side rejects with a valid bounce. All this cannot be done in java script alone.

Answer (score -1):

There is no point just checking if an email is "valid" without confirming that your user "owns" that email account. So therefore the only way to confirm an email address is valid AND is actually owned by that user is to send them a verification email.

In your email you'll include a unique code, and store that in the database.

Then in the email get them to click on the link to your website where you validate the unique code. This allows you to confirm the email address.

Once the user has confirmed their email address - then let them login into your site

Comment: Another option which some sites use quite elegantly is to allow login immediately, but disable some features until the email address has been verified.